# How to use MySQL functions when building a query with Zend/PDO

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo

I'm using Zend Framework with the PDO MySQL adapter and I want to use a function in my insert statement. Basically, the SQL I want to generate is this:

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`leftId`, `rightId`, `date`) VALUES ($left, $right, NOW())
```

This is the code in my Model:

```
$data = array(
    "leftId" => $left,
    "rightId" => $right,
    "date" => "NOW()"
);

$this->insert($data);
```

This tries to insert `"NOW()"` rather than `NOW()`:

> General error: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()' for column 'date' at row 1

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 26):

Found it [in the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.insert)*:

```
$data = array(
    "leftId" => $left,
    "rightId" => $right,
    "date" => new Zend_Db_Expr("NOW()")
);
```

<sub>`*`*I know, can you believe it?*</sub>

Comment: What if I've got it this way already and see the same error? u.u